# How to detect when a pressed mouse enters a widget in a different Frame

Tags: python, drag-and-drop, tkinter

I have a ttk Treeview (in a Frame in a Tk)) and a tk Listbox (in a Toplevel). My intention is to do the following:

1. press mouse button 1 in the Treeview
2. move (the pressed) mouse over to the Listbox
3. set the focus to the Toplevel containing the Listbox when the mouse enters

Right now I can set the focus of the Toplevel when an unpressed mouse enters. I used `.bind("<Enter>")`.

When I use `.bind("<B1-Motion>")` I can detect movement of a pressed mouse. But only if I pressed the mouse within the list.

When I use`.bind("<B1-Enter>")`I don't get any events.

How can I detect if a somewhere else pressed mouse enters my Listbox?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will need to set a binding on `<B1-Motion>`. Then, in the callback you can use the `winfo_containing` method to determine which widget is under the cursor. You can use `event.x_root` and `event.y_root` as arguments to `winfo_containing` to find the widget:

```
self.bind_all("<B1-Motion>", self.on_motion)
...
def on_motion(self, event):
    widget = self.winfo_containing(event.x_root, event.y_root)
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you very, very much! Btw...after searching for tk GUI stuff it was always you who gave the perfect answer :) .

Comment: Is there anyway to just get the `class` or the main widget? Like for `.!enter` just to get `.`, ie, root or for `tasks.!label1` to get `tasks` ?

Comment: @CoolCloud: the `winfo_*` commands can give you the information  you seek. `winfo_parent`, `winfo_class`, etc.